# AWS API Gateway + Firehose package multiple records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We have an application which accepts 10K requests/second, put them into S3 and then process them.

Currently we're using Kafka but we would like to replace it with Firehose for different reasons (maintenance, cost, etc). I configured API Gateway with Firehose and without any coding I was able to store my requests in S3 in parquet files.

Now comes cost estimation. From Amazon [example](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-log-analytics-solution/services-costs/) 500 records/second will cost 216 $ / month. The record size is rounded up to 5Kb. In our case 10K requests/second will cost 20 times more.

Our record size is 1.5k. So it makes sense to package multiple records into one. I did not find an example of how to do it easily. I don't want to implement this application by myself because there are many edge cases to be managed. And for me it seems to be pretty common case which should be already implemented.

Is there a standard way (AWS service, github project, etc) which can be used to package records?

Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: I think your bigger cost here is going to be API Gateway at $3.50/M requests.  At 10k req/s, you hit 1M requests every 100 seconds, so more than $3.50 every two minutes.  Even at the higher volume bulk rates (down to $1.51/M requests) this looks to cost over $40k/mo.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild, yes you're absolutely right. I completely missed this part. Indeed, in this case it makes no sense to migrate. Thank you very much for pointing this out.